# Incorrect data being binded in code behind c#

Tags: c#, behind

I am using the following code in my code behind to pull data from SQL in my class library.

The SQL is seemingly be pulled correctly, as the line:

```
int whatis = Convert.ToInt32(Global.rowcount);
```

shows the correct number of rows for the result of the SQL query.

But by inserting the code:

```
string test = Global.dsICD.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
string test2 = Global.dsICD.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString();
```

The Data being displayed is from a previous query.

The variable dsICD is only being used in this method in my solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

The full code is:

```cs
private void ICD10_ListViewBind(string ClientID)
{
    ICD10 icd = new ICD10();
    try
    {
        Global.rowcount = 0;
        Global.dsICD = null;
        ICD10_ListView.DataSource = null;
        Global.dsICD = icd.get_ICD10(ClientID);
        Global.row = Global.dsICD.Tables["tbl_Table"].Rows[0];
        Global.rowcount = Global.dsICD.Tables["tbl_Table"].Rows.Count;
        int whatis = Convert.ToInt32(Global.rowcount);
        ICD10_ListView.DataSource = Global.dsICD;
        string test = Global.dsICD.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
        string test2 = Global.dsICD.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString();
        ICD10_ListView.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        ex.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using Global variables, not MVVM. The best recommandation that I can do to you is... clean up your code, avoid any bad practices and use correct design pattern. Doing quick stuff in a durty maners will alway lead to bugs.
1 - Clean your code
2 - Use correct design patterns.
3- Clear your head from spaghetti code.
And your question is too broad, or you do not show enaugh code to allow you to answer to  your question
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is it possible your query is returning multiple result sets?  That is, is there more than one SELECT statement embedded in the query `get_ICD10()`?  In one line of code, you reference `Global.dsICD.Tables["tbl_Table"]`, and in another, `Global.dsICD.Tables[0]`.  If you are returning more than one set of rows, then these two references are not necessarily equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the advice Mat! :) 
I changed the code:

```
ICD10_ListView.DataSource = Global.dsICD.Tables;
```

to

```
ICD10_ListView.DataSource = Global.dsICD.Tables["tbl_Table"];
```

and it now works..